# Chaining jQuery .wrap() with .after()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so I am writing a small plugin...nothing big, but I ran across this issue (stripped down to show isolated problem)

My Plugin uses jQuery `.wrap()` and in this example I'll be using `.after()` as well.

```
(function( $ ) {

    var newWrap = $('<div/>');

    $.fn.smartform = function() { 

        this.wrap(newWrap);
        return this;

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Implementation mixed with `.after()`

```
$(document).on('click', '#addInput', function(){

    var newInput = $('<input/>').smartform().val('Just Added');
    $(this).after(newInput);

});
```

My function returns the correct targeted object properly since I see the value of the new input is 'Just Added' but the input does not get wrapped and I don't understand why.

I can get it to work this way (below) but it is not ideal as depending on how the new element is inserted ( `.append` `.before` `.after` ) will force traversing differently to target the newly added element.

```
$(document).on('click', '#addInput', function(){

    var newInput = $('<input/>').val('Just Added');
    $(this).after(newInput).next('input').smartform();

});
```

Any thoughts would be great, If you have any questions fell free to ask...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `newInput` is referring to the `input` element you have created, which is still not part of the dom. When you wrap the input the wrapper is created only in memory not in the dom.

So when you use `newInput` in `after()`, the input is removed form the in memory `div` and is inserted after the `button` so the wrapper element is lost.

```
$(document).on('click', '#addInput', function () {

    var newInput = $('<input/>').smartform().val('Just Added');
    $(this).after(newInput.parent());

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k6v1euoq/)

Comment: Thak you for the quick response! :) I somewhat follow what you are saying...still thinking about it though. I take it the `.parent()` is referring to the new `div` wrapper? Can this be handled within the jquery plugin function instead?

Comment: @VIDesignz http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k6v1euoq/4/ - this is case the returned value will be the `div` not the `input`

Comment: I see using `return this.parent();` within the plugin function does the trick, though I lose the ability to chain.

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle, I guess some functions just can't be chained. This is waaaay better than what I had in the first place.

Comment: @VIDesignz another choice will be to pass where to append the element - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k6v1euoq/7/

Comment: Wow, that is GREAT! Maintains the ability to chain! Thank you so much! I take it the 'append' is the default correct?

Comment: Can you help me again? I am having trouble wrapping my head around this. I added to your fiddle and went another level deeper. Towards the bottom you will see a `.before()` and a `.prepend()` chained. The `.prepend()` works but the `.before()`does not... I am sure it has something to do with the order in which thing are created as you answered before yet I am unfamiliar with the `.map()` and what it did, nor am I able to fully grasp what all the `returns` are returning and in which order...can you guide me and comment within the fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/k6v1euoq/14/

Comment: @VIDesignz sure... can you have a constraint like the plugin will always be called on a single element, not not a set of more than 1 element... you current design suggests so...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61192/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-videsignz).